# Dynamic object against Interface Method

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, interface

I'm rewriting a desktop solution and I have the main root Form, that contains Properties that should be accessible by other elements of the application.

You could use an Interface method to get the property or your could get the Form as a dynamic object and query the property.  Code example below.

**Interface-based approach**

```
public interface IUersInterfaceMainScreenGet
{  
    dynamic GetClientDetails();  
}
```

The forms interface-implementation looks like this:

```
public dynamic GetClientDetails()
{
    return currentClients;
}
```

Calling the Interface

```
 var mainScreen = (InterfaceProject.IUersInterfaceMainScreenGet)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["mainScreenForm"];
 return mainScreen.GetLastBodyPluginFormName();
```

**Dynamic-based appraoch**

```
dynamic form = Application.OpenForms["MainScreenForm"];
form.currentClients
```

Both instance needs to get the current Active form, but Which once would be the best in practice to memory usage?

With the Interface the Property that I want to get can be private, but for Dynamic it needs to be public

Comment: Basically it´s always good idea to know the exact types you can expect at compile-time because you have safety on what you can access on that specific type. So as long as you do not *really* need *dynamic* don´t use it.

Comment: Yes it was..  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite hard to understand. However I have a guess on what you mean.

When you have your interface you can get the clients details via a method called `GetClientDetails`. On the form its implementation simply returns the private field (**not property**) `currentClients`.

Usually it´s a good idea to know the types you handle with, so using interfaces is a good idea as you have compile-time checks on what you *can* access and what not. In your case you kno that the object returned from `Forms.Application.OpenForms["mainScreenForm"]` has a method for accessing the client-details. When using only `dynamic` you have no knowledge at all on the contained object, you could do *everything* with it - whereas the most will fail at *runtime*. But why do you want to throw away knowledge that you already *have*?

So my basic suggestion is: allways use strongly-typed interfaces. Only in a few seldom circumstances you may actually *need* `dynamic`.

Concerning the memory-footprint there is no difference between both solutions. What counts is the memory of your actual *instance*, which is the same, no matter on how you *access* the data. So you need a field in both cases. The only difference is how you *access* that field, one time you this happens directly (`dynamic`) and on the interface you access it by calling the method.

So there is no difference on the following two statements concerning memory-footprint:

```
 var form = (IUersInterfaceMainScreenGet)Application.OpenForms["mainScreenForm"];
 return form.GetClientDetails();
```

And

```
dynamic form = Application.OpenForms["MainScreenForm"];
return form.currentClients
```

Comment: Thanks.  So really it the amount of code needed for the Interface.  But with the interface you can know the type of object that your dealing with.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure the logic and the practice used going forward for the new solution is right.  The logic needs to be able to be called from anywhere within the solution and be flexible at the sametime.

Comment: You should ask yourself if the form allways have client-details which I assume it should. So why do you want to throw that knowledge away and rely on your app crashing when there are no details?